# Simplify multiple joins

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a `Claims` table with 70 columns, 16 of which contain diagnosis codes.  The codes mean nothing, so I need to pull the descriptions for each code located in a separate table.

There has to be a simpler way of pulling these code descriptions:

```
-- This is the claims table
FROM 
    [database].[schema].[claimtable] AS claim

-- [StagingDB].[schema].[Diagnosis] table where the codes located
-- [ICD10_CODE] column contains the code
LEFT JOIN 
    [StagingDB].[schema].[Diagnosis] AS diag1 ON claim.[ICDDiag1] = diag1.[ICD10_CODE]
LEFT JOIN 
    [StagingDB].[schema].[Diagnosis] AS diag2 ON claim.[ICDDiag2] = diag2.[ICD10_CODE]
LEFT JOIN 
    [StagingDB].[schema].[Diagnosis] AS diag3 ON claim.[ICDDiag3] = diag3.[ICD10_CODE]
-- and so on, up to ....
LEFT JOIN 
    [StagingDB].[schema].[Diagnosis]AS diag16 ON claim.[ICDDiag16] = diag16.[ICD10_CODE]

-- reported column will be [code_desc]
-- ie: 
-- diag1.[code_desc] AS Diagnosis1
-- diag2.[code_desc] AS Diagnosis2
-- diag3.[code_desc] AS Diagnosis3
-- diag4.[code_desc] AS Diagnosis4
-- etc.
```

Comment: Is this on SQL Server? If so, what version?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio v17.7

Comment: What you have is a very poor table structure.  What would be easier is a claims table with a CHILD table of all diagnosis codes associated with a given claim, then the query would be much simpler to handle.  Are you locked into this table structure design or can you restructure for more efficient means.  Having worked with claims adjudication systems before, what you have will be a nightmare, let alone any real data-mining performance.

Comment: @DRapp You should see how these DBs are setup... no data governance whatsoever, literally thousands of tables, with some random names so you have no idea what you're looking at...  JOINS upon JOINS for any query.  We do utilize child tables...  I know what you're saying though... It didn't even cross my mind.  I'll have to dive in.  Thanks!

Comment: Management Studio is *not* the SQL Server, its just a client interface and as such can be a different version to the engine it is accessing. To find the version `select @@version`.

Comment: If you only want ` column from the `[Diagnosis]` table you can use a sub-query rather than a join, but I imagine performance will be about the same.

Comment: "I have a Claims table with 70 columns, 16 of which contain diagnosis codes." There's your problem right there. Poor database design will lead to cumbersome code with performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are doing is already correct in given scenario.

Another way can be from programming point of view or you can give try and compare ther performace.

i) Pivot Claim table on those 16 description columns.
ii) Join the Pivoted column with `[StagingDB].[schema].[Diagnosis]`

Another way can be to put `[StagingDB].[schema].[Diagnosis]` table in some `#temp` table
instead of touching large Staging 16 times.

But for data analysis has to be done to decide if there is any way.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for UNPIVOT of the claimTable and then join with Diagnosis table.

**TEST SETUP**

```sql
create table #claimTable(ClaimId INT, Diag1 VARCHAR(10), Diag2 VARCHAR(10))
CREATE table #Diagnosis(code VARCHAR(10), code_Desc VARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO #ClaimTable
VALUES (1, 'Fever','Cold'), (2, 'Headache','toothache');

INSERT INTO #Diagnosis
VALUEs ('Fever','Fever Desc'), ('cold','cold desc'),('headache','headache desc'),('toothache','toothache desc');
```

**Query to Run**

```sql
;WITH CTE_Claims AS
(SELECT ClaimId,DiagnosisNumeral, code
FROM #claimTable
UNPIVOT
(
code FOR DiagnosisNumeral in ([Diag1],[Diag2])
) as t
)
SELECT c.ClaimId, c.code, d.code_Desc
FROM CTE_Claims AS c
INNER JOIN #Diagnosis as d
on c.code = d.code
```

**ResultSet**

```
+---------+-----------+----------------+
| ClaimId |   code    |   code_Desc    |
+---------+-----------+----------------+
|       1 | Fever     | Fever Desc     |
|       1 | Cold      | cold desc      |
|       2 | Headache  | headache desc  |
|       2 | toothache | toothache desc |
+---------+-----------+----------------+
```

Comment: Although the unpivot is a consideration, if you are dealing with a medical adjudication claims system, you will have millions of transactions, and unpivoting mostly blank will not be practical.  They really need to update their structure for long-term performance.  This post does not have a "simple fix" query solution... it goes much deeper than that.